# Is it possible that run ads in android built-in apps through own app?

Tags: android, android-service, android-permissions

I want to run ads in android built-in apps activity , if ads block through my app then ads cannot display in the built-in apps activity,for example if we open the messaging app then ads display if this ads block from my app the ads cannot be display in message app, please help me this problem.

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question, try expanding it? What do you mean by "built-in apps"? It sounds like you want to place an advertisement over another application. This would not be possible unless that particular app supports ads, and in that case I would assume you would have to contact the developer (or their ad provider) to place your ads within their app.

Comment: Thanx. my question is that my smart phone apps which is already installed   in phone like messaging app, or File Manager app, or voice Dialer app , Contacts app etc, can we create the connection my own created app with smart phone apps as like messaging app , when the messaging app is launch  then ad display in messaging app if we want to block this ad it should be done through my own created  app.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. I don't think anything you are trying to do is possible. I still don't know if I fully understand your question, but I think you want to do one of two things. Either you want to show your own ads in a pre-existing app, or you want to create a kind of universal ad-blocker. Both of these are not possible.

The only connections you can make to other applications is through what are called [`Intents`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html). `Intents` basically send a message to another app to handle a request made by your application. But the basis of `Intents` is that an application must built to handle specific `Intents`. If you send an `Intent` to an application that does not support that specific `Intent`, the `Intent` will be rejected.

Therefore, displaying or blocking advertisements within other applications just is not supported, nor should it be. Unless an application supports this functionality through an `Intent`, there is no way of *telling* another app to display or block an advertisement. And, as far as I know, there are no apps that support this.